# How to fix the large consumption of RAM python asyncio problem?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

In their spiders usually'm using such a pillar:

```
 async def crawl(future, client, pool):
        futures = []
        urls = await future
        for request_future in asyncio.as_completed([request(client, url) for url in urls]):
            parse_future = loop.run_in_executor(pool, parse, (await request_future))
            futures.append(asyncio.ensure_future(crawl(parse_future, client, pool)))
        if futures:
            await asyncio.wait(futures)
```

Everything would be fine, but when there are a large number of links, then after executing the request to the server (request), the result is saved, and then it will be processed by the pool by the thread.

That's exactly when it is stored, a large amount of RAM is consumed (now almost 8 GB).

Is it possible to somehow change this design so that after the request, the result is immediately processed, well, or saved up to a certain amount (for example 50), and then the thread pool is quickly processed.

those. I need to reduce RAM consumption to acceptable, but not lose the benefits of asynchronous requests